# What is this wildflower with 4 petals, white with purple spots?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

What is this wildflower with 4 symmetrical petals, white with purple spots, lanceolate leaves? The plant is about a foot high.

[image: a closeup of the stem and leaf]

[image: close up of the flower]

[image: and a not very good picture of the plant]

I live in the middle Himalayas (about 1600m above sea level) and it's just entering autumn here.

Comment: Is it possible to post a couple more photos, one showing the plant overall to display growth habit and one showing the foliage please?

Comment: Added the photos, hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

@stormy, @Niall C.
Thank you!
This looks like it: [Swertia angustifolia](http://medplants.blogspot.in/2014/07/swertia-angustifolia.html)

The 'frasera' identification was a big help.After that, it was just a matter of hunting.
Thank you so much both for the identification and for introducing me to a beguiling group of plants

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't easy... try [Frasera albicaulis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frasera_albicaulis).  If you google this it'll show lots of pictures.

Comment: Mhm. Not entirely convinced. OP says it's from the Himalayas while frasera albicaulis is native to the NW US. Flowers also seem a bit "distant" for frasera albicaulis. *Very similar* though, perhaps a close relative?

Comment: I agree, this plant is not a match.  But I might try growing it in my garden, thanks!

Comment: Yea, not a match, more like Leontopodium, or Eidelweiss - I can't help thinking the one pictured above is some sort of orchid... but I can't track it down, so maybe not.

Comment: It does have fleshy petals..but also has a taproot. Is that possible for an orchid? Apologies if the question is silly, but i really do not know about ground orchids!

Comment: Orchids have petals, sepals in groups of 3.  This plant isn't an orchid.  But I am glad Frasera led you to Swertia...helped.  I actually came across Swertia in Nepal but the pictures were terrible.  What a cool plant!  The chemistry is facinating!  Good for you!